# Docker via snap - Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on a year old installation

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, snapcraft

I've had Docker installed via Snap on Ubuntu 18.04 a year or so ago. I have around 5 images on there and worked quite a bit on them.

Today I get to work and the command `sudo docker start 0e0` gives me:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I have not used snap in quite some time and been mostly doing apt-get updates and upgrades. Last one I did was three days ago, on Monday. I haven't used docker in that time and have restated my computer only once - yesterday.

Having forgotten I installed it via snap, I try to restart the service using `systemctl start docker` and `service start docker` but:

```
Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.
```

I decide to reinstall docker and do `apt-get remove docker` and `apt-get install docker`. Apparently I also had it installed via apt-get, (but not worked with it?????), as the remove worked. I try `systemctl` and `service` again but same output. That's when I recall that I used snap to install it.

At this point I do `sudo snap remove docker`, not being well accustomed with snap, I stop the process four times because it was taking too long - unbeknownst to me it was creating a snapshot. The fifth time it created it successfully. I run: `sudo snap install docker`. Docker works, `ps -a` returns an empty list, so does `images`.

When I see all the container and volume data gone, I realise snap create a snapshot and run `sudo snap restore 5`. Data is restored, but `docker images` still returns an empty list. Thinking it needs a restart, I do `sudo snap restart docker`.

Docker restart successfully, doing `ps -a` returns:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Back at the starting point.

Running `snap logs docker`, returns:

```
2020-08-27T09:19:35Z systemd[1]: Started Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
2020-08-27T09:19:36Z docker.dockerd[24590]: failed to start daemon: Error saving key file: open /etc/docker/.tmp-key.json485929544: no such file or directory
2020-08-27T09:19:36Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2020-08-27T09:19:36Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2020-08-27T09:19:36Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
2020-08-27T09:19:36Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
2020-08-27T09:19:36Z systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
2020-08-27T09:19:36Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
2020-08-27T09:19:36Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2020-08-27T09:19:36Z systemd[1]: Failed to start Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
```

That log was around the time I tried to start the container I wanted to use (having realised I restarted the computer the day prior).

Docker is version: `Docker version 19.03.11, build dd360c7` after doing the snap re-install and restore.

What should I do to have a working docker, preferably through snap (now that I know how it works I quite like the concept), and restore all the images that are still on the disk?

Can I, for example, create a clean new installation via apt-get and "import" the images, volumes and containers I have on my disk?

---

P.S.
In general I'm writing this question so meticulously due to two factors: 99% of the questions and answers I found on docker not being able to connect to the docker daemon were either not installed via snap or were fresh installations.

---

EDIT:

27-08-2020 12:13

The folder /etc/docker doesn't exist at all and the docker installation is in /var/snap/docker

Doing `sudo systemctl stop snap.docker.dockerd.service` and `sudo systemctl start snap.docker.dockerd.service` finds the services but docker returns the same error. `sudo snap services docker` returns:

```
Service         Startup  Current   Notes
docker.dockerd  enabled  inactive  -
```

What's more bizzare, is that `sudo snap start docker` gives `Started.` and running `services` again gives

```
Service         Startup  Current   Notes
docker.dockerd  enabled  active    -
```

but when I do `sudo docker ps -a` and check `services`, Current goes back to inactive.

27-08-2020 14:06

After actually and properly installing docker-ce via apt-get I have realised I didn't have docker fully installed previously. I'm trying to find if moving images, containers and volumes from snaps directory to apt-gets docker is possible. Haven't found an answer yet.